# Suggestions related to Android final application?

Tags: android

i have completed my First android application and i have deployed that application to different android based mobile phones

which is working fine.

my question to you is, is there iphone store like thing exists in android to upload your application by paying fee to android store or something like that..

or nothing or should i start passing my application to end users directly?

any help would be appriciated.

Comment: So you've researched your app's functionality doesn't already exist on the market then...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah there is the Android Marketplace which you can find more details on at http://market.android.com/publish It costs $25 once off to register and you're free to upload your applications (which are available almost instantly)

Answer (score 0):

Both is possible. You can distribute your app via the AndroidMarket and at the same time just share the apk file.

Comment: is it legal if we start passing application directly to users?